# How should I design index in ElasticSearch for schema less documents with user defined fields

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene

Currently we use Mysql as database for our multi-tenant web application, in order to improve our search we decided to move to ElasticSearch. We have an Entity in Mysql with some base fields and every tenant can define his own custom fields(can be of any data type) for that entity. What are the best practices for designing index in elastic search for above problems? 
Will dynamic mapping work fine in the above case.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch is great tool to define custom fields, you simply can index data without define nothing.

In some cases you have to define fields mapping, for example in date field or Geo point field, if you don't mapping this field, elastic will not treat this field as you wish.
So if your custom fields is not date or Geo point you can allow tenant define custom fields.